# I can't install Cordova within the command-line

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: semver@'^4.3.x'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","1.0.10","1.0.11","1.0.12","1.0.13","1.0.14","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","2.0.0-alpha","2.0.0-beta","2.0.1","2.0.2","2.0.3","2.0.4","2.0.5","2.0.6","2.0.7","2.0.8","2.0.9","2.0.10","2.0.11","2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","3.0.0","3.0.1","4.0.0","4.0.2","4.0.3","4.1.0","4.1.1","4.2.0","4.2.1","4.2.2","4.3.0","4.3.1","4.3.2","4.3.3","4.3.4","4.3.5","4.3.6","5.0.0","5.0.1"]
npm ERR! at installTargetsError (C:\Program  Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR! at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:638:10
npm ERR! at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:142:7)
npm ERR! at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR! at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Hafeedh
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hafeedh\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
C:\Users\Hafeedh>
```

Comment: this is the error message in cmd

Comment: what you want from cordova? i mean want you want to implement??

Comment: Which command did you type to install Cordova (Please update your question with more details)? try running `npm install cordova -g` and show us the output.

Comment: i do " npm install -g cordova" but i don't undestand where is exactly this error.

Comment: 0.10.15 is kind of an old Node version, I suggest you remove your current Node installation, install the latest Node (v0.12.7 at the moment), and then try to install Cordova.

Comment: yes this is the good response. thinks

Comment: Did it work out for you ?

Comment: I resolve my problem thinks

Comment: I used a newer version of node js